# Adding 'where' in Entity Framework query didn't work?

Tags: entity-framework

```
        ERPEntities dbEntities = new ERPEntities();
        var clsCode = "001";
        var items = dbEntities.clsitem.Select(aa => aa);
        if (clsCode != null)
            items.Where(aa => aa.clscode == clsCode);
        var _test = items.ToList();
```

There are 21 rows in table `clsitem`.

After executing, the result of `_test.Count()` is 21 (which means that `item.where()`) didn't work.

But if I use `var _test = dbEntities.clsitem.Where(aa => aa.clscode == clsCode);`, then I'll get what I expecte.

Why ?

How can I get filtered data if I need to have a If expression to see wheather `clsCode` is not null before executing the query? (I don't want to get the whole data in database)

Comment: Why are you writing C# without ReSharper? It would complain that the result of a pure function is unused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You not get result of items. `Where` does not change source collection. This method returns new collection.

```
    ERPEntities dbEntities = new ERPEntities();
    var clsCode = "001";
    var items = dbEntities.clsitem.Select(aa => aa);
    if (clsCode != null)
        items = items.Where(aa => aa.clscode == clsCode); // this string
    var _test = items.ToList();
```